# WSO2 BPMN UserTask: Dynamic Form data

Tags: wso2, activiti, bpmn, wso2-business-process

We are currently working on wso2 BPMN user tasks.  In the user task, usually we will be able to
define the variables and parameters for the form to be displayed for the user when the task is
created. Is it possible to define the parameters of the form dynamically (post-deployment/runtime), say,

Eg-1: Based on the incoming parameters we define the number of parameters to be displayed

Eg-2: Option for template import, based on which the parameters would be displayed to the user

Comment: I tried using the activiti:formKey property, however it is not generating the form in task screen.

 _<userTask id="usertask1" name="User Task" activiti:assignee="admin" activiti:formKey="conf/user.html"></userTask>_ 

Please let me know id I am missing something

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think that is possible, but you will need to code that logic into the forms. Which version are you using, and which front end are you using?

Cheers

Comment: I am currently using WSO2 EI 6.1.1 and using the BPMN-explorer itself since we are in prototyping stage. 

Also, as mentioned above, I tried using the activiti:formKey property, 
however it is not generating the form in task screen.

**<userTask id="usertask1" name="User Task" activiti:assignee="admin" activiti:formKey="conf/user.html"></userTask>**

Please let me know if I am missing something. Also mention if there are any better alternatives (w.r.t configuration)

Comment: I do work for the Activiti team, not the WSO2 EI 6.1.1 so probably they will need to comment here. Not sure how that "conf/user.html" works. if it  is a key it shouldn't be a pointer to a file it should just be a key that then is used to locate the correct form.

Comment: Currently, I am giving the location of the file in the formKey. Plz let me know what should be the correct configuration. What do you mean by "key which used to locate the form"?

Comment: Understood. As you had mentioned, I was using the file location instead of configuring a key. But, how to generate the key that can be used ot locate the form?